# How to display rows with multiple hits?

Tags: sql

If I run

```
SELECT somecolumn FROM sometable GROUP BY somecolumn HAVING count(*) > 1;
```

the output will have values for `somecolumn` that appear more than once in `sometable`.

But I want to see the *rows* (or parts of them) where these repeated values appear.  E.g., if `foo` and `bar` are names for the other columns from `sometable` that are of interest, the first few rows of the output may look something like

```
 somecolumn |  foo   |  bar
-------------------------------
 123        | foo_1  | bar_2
 123        | foo_3  | bar_5
 123        | foo_7  | bar_11
 234        | foo_13 | bar_17
 234        | foo_19 | bar_23
...
```

etc.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Which rdbms are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a database agnostic solution, you can do this:

```
SELECT *
FROM sometable S
WHERE somecolumn IN (   SELECT somecolumn 
                        FROM sometable 
                        GROUP BY somecolumn 
                        HAVING count(*) > 1)
```

For SQL Server 2005+, you can do this:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  *,
            N = COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY somecolumn)
    FROM sometable
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE N > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add those column to the selection as well as the grouping

```
SELECT 
    somecolumn, 
    foo, 
    bar 
FROM 
    sometable 
GROUP BY 
    somecolumn, 
    foo, 
    bar 
HAVING count(*) > 1;
```

Comment: This isn't what op wants. S/he wants to know the values for the other columns when only somecolumn is duplicated